# Ruby mark instance variable as unassignable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is it possible to mark an instance variable such as @var as unassingnable, such that the following test would pass? The aim is simulate a readonly variable:

```
class Test
  def initialize(var)
    @var = var
    @var.freeze
    make_unassignable(:@var)
  end

  def set_var(new_var)
    @var = new_var
  end

  def make_unassignable(symbol)
    #insert algorithm here
  end
end

test = Test.new('some var')

expect { test.set_var = 'some other var' }.to raise_error
expect { test.instance_variable_set(:@var, 'some other var') }.to raise_error
```

Comment: @Andrey: Please remove the duplicate flag. The question you have given is similar but I am asking about disabling the ability to assign a variable altogether (not just build protections via exceptions).

Comment: Thank you for explaining that.

Comment: please unaccept my answer since it does not answer the question about making variable unassignable (which is not possible, as another answer correctly states)

Comment: There are read-only variables in Ruby (for example `$<`), but Ruby doesn't expose this feature through its API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Variables are variable in Ruby, always. In fact, even constants are variable in Ruby, they only generate a warning when re-assigned.

Comment: Overwritten `instance_variable_set` on `Test`’s eigenclass might drastically hamper it’s resetting (not to make it _impossible_, though.)